# A basic question about concave function.

Tags: functions

Question:

> Let  $f: \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a concave
> function satisfying  $f(0)=0 $. Show that for all  $k \geq 1 $ we have
> $k f(x) \geq f(k x) $. What happens if $ k \in[0,1)  ?$

I know that when $ k \in [0,1)$, by the definition of concave function and the condition given, $f(0) = 0$, we can show that $kf(x) \leq f(kx)$. But when $k \geq 1,$ I don't know how to prove this conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you could deal with the $k<1$ case because $kx$ was in between $0$ and $x$ and you could apply concavity.

Now if $k\geq 1$ which of $0,kx$ and $x$ is between the two others ? What can you deduce ?

Comment: oh! I knew it! That's awesome!